# Optional authentication for Java EE Resource

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish

I would like to protect a SOAP JAX-WS webservice with a java security authentication but, because a lot of users are already using it, i don't want to ask them to implement the authentication on their side.

The idea is to permit the access to everybody to the WS (no login required, as is right now) but if anyone pass newly authentication HTTP Basic login i will detect it (`request.getUserPrincipal()`) and i will enable some new functionalities.

I'm trying to use java security but i didn't find how to specify that the basic authentication is OPTIONAL for a specific security-constraint and not required. This is a problem because if i use it i cannot grant anonymous access anymore.

I'm using Java EE 5 on Glassish v2.1.1

Example:

```
@WebService
public class MyWs {

  @Resource
  protected WebServiceContext wsContext;

  @WebMethod()
  public void myWebMethod(){
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) wsContext.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
    if (request.getPrincipal() != null && request.getPrincipal().getName().equals("myAuthenticatedUser")){
      //do something new
    }
    //do the same as before
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's optional, why would you bother securing it?

Comment: because i want to add new functionalities into the webmethod and i want that those new functionalities wil be enabled only for a restricted set of users and not for everybody.